# cURL to HTTPS website failing with error:140770FC:SSL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, tls1.2

I'm trying to cURL a website from different machines. When I run the following command on my Air laptop the response is OK.

```
curl https://www.tesoralia.com --verbose
```

However, if I run it on my Linux server I get the following error:

```
Rebuilt URL to: https://www.tesoralia.com/
Trying 2001:8d8:931:371:eb4b:6a4b:f158:0...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to www.tesoralia.com (2001:8d8:931:371:eb4b:6a4b:f158:0) port 443 (#0)
Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Both machines have the same setting: **SSLv3/TLSv1.2**

I've tried using --insecure but doesn't work either.

Is the website blocking my IP?

Comment: seen similar problems countless times, its almost always an old & fixed openssl/curl bug. update both. what does this command say? `curl --version` - both on the Air and on the linux box?

Comment: @hanshenrik the Air says: curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy

Comment: @hanshenrik and the Linux: curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy

Comment: update your linux box's curl/libopenssl then :) will probably fix it

Comment: Looks like there are some issues with that IPv6 address -- try `curl ... --ipv4`.